# What is the proper file structure of a module that only contains sub-modules?

Tags: 7

I have put together a module package that has 3 sub-modules. They must be contained in a single folder to be distributed and used by other devs. Are there drupal best practices for how a module's files structure should be if it contains just multiple modules?

e.g.

```
name_of_module/modules/module1/module1.info
name_of_module/modules/module2/module2.info
name_of_module/modules/module3/module3.info
```

or

```
name_of_module/module1/module1.info
name_of_module/module2/module2.info
name_of_module/module3/module3.info
```

or?

Answer (score 3):

For what i've seen, putting sub modules in a modules folder like your first example is most common best practice.

Comment: Agreed.  Views does this, as does Rules.  Though, I think most also put the common / base module at the top-level.

Comment: In commerce it's done like that aa well.

Answer (score 2):

There aren't Drupal best practices about where to put submodules. You could:

- Put them in a separated sub-directory of "modules" contained in the directory containing the main module
- Put them in a separated sub-directory of the directory containing the main module
- Put them in the same directory containing the main module

Any of those directory structures is used:

- The [Views](http://drupalcode.org/project/views.git/tree/refs/heads/7.x-3.x) module has a "modules" sub-directory, but that is not for sub-modules; both view.module and views_ui.module are in the same directory that contains the main module.
- The [CCK](http://drupalcode.org/project/cck.git/tree/refs/heads/6.x-3.x) module has a "modules" directory where all the sub-modules are each contained in a separated directory.
- The [Panels](http://drupalcode.org/project/panels.git/tree/refs/heads/7.x-3.x) module has its sub-modules saved in a separated directory contained in the main directory.
- The Views Bonus Pack module uses three different sub-directories of the main directory.

There isn't actually a reason related to how Drupal handles modules, to choose a structure or another one.
There is a reason to choose the first two structures instead of the third one, and that is generally that each module comes with other files that are grouped in directories with the same name (e.g., css, js, templates), and you don't want to mix files that are for different modules.

Answer (score 0):

I do the second one. Also please realize that the modules directory in Views does not contain modules at all.