# What is it called when a Drupal Module installs with several modules?

Tags: 7

I looked up submodule, but that seems to be a Git thing. So, when a Drupal module installs with a whole group of things that show up in the dashboard, what is each piece called? For example, there are about 8 items that show up in Modules -> Chaos Tool Suite. If they show up in one group, does that mean they are all written by the same entity?

Answer (score 2):

> what is each piece called?

I don't have an official reference, but "submodules" or "sub-modules" is by far the most common phrase I've seen used for modules included in a main module to complement/extend its functionality. Prominent members of the Drupal community [seem comfortable with referring to them as such](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34934/what-is-the-proper-file-structure-of-a-module-that-only-contains-sub-modules).

> If they show up in one group, does that mean they are all written by the same entity?

It can in some cases, but there's nothing to guarantee it. Any module can list itself under any of those groups by setting the `package` key in its .info file. A lot of modules that provide field types list themselves under the generic "Fields" group, for example.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then, I could write a module, designate it as CCK by setting the "package key, and it would show up in the CCK group. That sounds like hijacking someone else's module to me. Do I have that right?

Comment: It's not really hijacking, it's organization and most of us developer types like to be organized :) I love the submodule term and I also like that I can create a custom module that may hook into a normal contrib module like views and have that functionality grouped as such on the modules page (or modules list in drush, I rarely actually visit the modules page after all) and later on myself or some other developer can see by the grouping that a module in the `/custom` directory offers some sort of views code or something like that. So while it may not seem important now, it could be later.

Comment: It's open source @Nora, you don't really have the concept of "someone else's module"; it's just "a module". Drupal was designed to allow for arbitrary modules to be grouped together for display on the main modules page, so no, I wouldn't call it hijacking myself, just making good use of the tools available

Comment: @burnsjeremy I'm not certain that comments is the correct place to ask this, but where is /custom? I don't believe I have ever seen that directory in any of the Drupal sites I've worked on (most all my Drupal work is in Drupal 7).

Comment: There is also one of these in the themes folder but this is the README for sites/all/modules for D7 http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/sites/all/modules/README.txt?h=7.x and for D8 http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/modules/README.txt that should give you info about the /custom folder I referred to earlier.

Comment: To summarize what I think you both mean:
1. The module groupings in the Drupal dashboard are not author relevant, but are organized by function, which may be tied to a core module, such as Views.
2. If you install a module, it may install 1 - N submodules. 
3. If you install a module, that module may show up in a subgroup the writer chooses based on the package designation.
4. A "module" as found in the Drupal site, may install submodules in more than one group.
Am I understanding correctly?